# how do I split the street values into atomic in pl/sql?

Tags: regex, plsql, split, street-address

My task is to convert the non-atomic (Australian)street addresses into atomic which means current street data is stored as street number and street names together. Samples are:

```
24 George street        -----------> 24         |   George street    
55 park rd              -----------> 55         |   pard rd  
102a gordon road        -----------> 102a       |   gordon road
unit 5/46 addison ave   -----------> unit 5/46  |   addison ave 
flat 2-9/87 north avenue-----------> flat 2-9/87|   north avenue
suit 5 lvl2/55 prince hwy-------> suit 5 lvl2/55|   prince hwy
shop 5 Big Shopping Centre  ------> Rejected
Suit 2 Level 100          -------> Rejected
```

added data(the way the program should work):

```
Darling street ------------------> Rejected
City road -----------------------> rejected
```

the suggested code processed result:

```
Darling street ------------>   Darling     |    Street
City road   --------------->   City        |     road
```

actually in this case the code should not process the address and throw an exception.

What is the best way of splitting the addresses?

Comment: why should this rejected: 'shop 5 Big Shopping Centre' ?

Comment: @kaᵠ- because it is not a valid Australian address which post office ville return/reject the delivery, according to the specs of the task

Comment: I got that, but programs don't actually *understand* data, you need to teach them somehow. What would make that be rejected?

Comment: This is a fuzzy data matching requirement, and not simply solved with SQL on its own. We've had a modicum of success using a 3rd party tool like QAS (http://www.qas-experian.com.au/), I'm sure there are other similar tools out there.

Comment: How do you handle ambiguities such as:24 George Pt (meaning George Point) when the city is Pt. Macquarie.  So an address string such as: 24 George Pt Macquarie NSW?  Is it George Point or is is Port Macquarie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
   addr,
   regexp_substr(addr, '^(.*?)\s\D+$', 1, 1, '', 1) street_number,
   regexp_substr(addr, '^.*?\s+(\D*?)\s*$', 1, 1, '', 1) street_name
from t1   
where -- don't show rejected
   regexp_like(addr, '\d.*\s(street|road|rd|ave|avenue|hwy)\s*$', 'i')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a872c/2)

Comment: it works well, but what if there is no number at all in the street data. I is now taking the street name as street number in case there is no street number was recorded, is there anyway of preventing it to process if there is no number?

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli - Please add the address you are talking about to your question and give desired output.

Comment: @Skritunoff - The question was edited according to the comment above

Comment: @Skritunoff- can you please also tell me what has been changed in the fixed version as it is really difficult for a regexp beginner to distinguish the difference, please

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - suggestion - last line might be changed to `regexp_like(LOWER(addr), '\d.*\s(street|road|rd|ave|avenue|hwy)\s*$', 'i')` on the off-chance that someone might use UPPER or Mixed case when entering an address.  YMMV.

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli - Click on the time following the word `edited` under my answer to see the difference.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - my apologies - I didn't take the time to look at all the args.  :-}  Thanks.

Comment: @EgorSkritunoff- if you still see this, please can you give me some a few mor advice. How should the regexp be changed if PO Box 123 is regarded as valid address and do not need to be splited and it goes to direct streetname as whole. Also in Australia there are addresses which indicates the crossing corners like Cnr alice street & George road. Any clue please?

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli - use `where regexp_like(addr, 'PO\s*Box\s*\d+', 'i')` to select PO Boxes.  About corners I didn't understand.  There are four houses at every crossroad.  Which one of them is meant by `cnr street1 & street2`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have already seen the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-into-components) along the same lines.

@kaᵠ pointed out already that the program doesn't know anything about the data, thus it has no context.  This will always be the case.  So, with that in mind, the first thing you need to determine is what level of accuracy do you need?  If you need 70% accuracy then you can do that with simple REGEX.  (Is regex EVER really simple)?

If you need certainty that the addresses you extracted from the input are actually real and valid, you need a list or table to compare against. That data would come from a source like Australia Post (or USPS in the United States).

So, use your regex to extract "guesses" and then verify those against a master list and the ones that match are good.  Without the master list, you can't be sure that you got it right or that you got it wrong.

I have actually been working on this exact same issue at SmartyStreets (except I only deal with US addreses) and have come up with a number of different solutions - different ways to determine the beginning and end of the address string, as well as how to deal with false positives, or primary numbers that look just like a postal code. You can go pure REGEX or you can also use tables containing the postal codes, states, and also street names.  This enables you to get very close to being able to extract the atomic data with high accuracy.