# Cross Domain access to USPS Address validation API

Tags: ajax, cors, usps

I am trying to hit USPS address validation API by AJAX call and I am getting 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error.

However when I am trying to access the same address though URL, I am getting the results.

Has this error something to do with approval thing?

The id I am using for this has been approved and I am able to get the result by the API through URL.

I want to access it though scripting. Please help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do suggest you insert then exact text of your **error messages** here for the benefit of future googlers.  And/or use [FastStone Screen Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) for a visual.  (Sheesh I'm advertising today like a racecar driver.  Though less paid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you might want to do this is to have the Ajax requests go to your web server -- the same HTTP server where the page came from.  And then your server-side program (in PHP, or Python or whatever you're using) **relays the request to the USPS server**.

Making the request browser-side, from Ajax directly to the USPS server, is just the kind of suspicious activity (called Cross-Site Scripting) that browsers are learning to block.

[CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/673991) could theoretically be one way to unblock a Cross-Origin Request, but in that scheme it would be the USPS API server that ultimately grants that permission for pages from your domain.  [Tech detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example): by inserting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response to a request with an `Origin` header in the Ajax back-and-forth.

Comment: Thanks @BobStein, It worked, I made request to USPS server through server-side (C# ASP.NET) code and got the response.

Comment: Great @Hari!  I was about to ask you for code or specifics when I got it, you were trying to do what I was planning to do, and really should someday be the better solution (direct instead of relaying).  By the way I'm implementing a [free-form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11160192/673991) smartystreets [jQuery plugin](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin) instead, very class act.  Shame no one validates non-US addresses that well however.

Comment: Yes, right. I am struggling for Canada address validations.