# Regex PHP , postal address

Tags: php, regex

i know that regex on postal address cannot be optimal, but i really one here .

I explain my problem : I got different types of postal address :

- `32 Rue Jean Jaures 69000 Lyon`
- `Bâtiment 1 32 Rue Jean Jaures 69000 Lyon`
- `32 B Jean Jaures 69000 Lyon`
- `Bâtiment 1 32 B Rue Jean Jaures 69000 Lyon`

I need a regexp to find only the number of the street in any position.

I have done a regexp which permit to determine the number if it is at the beginning of the string :

```
`^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\s*[A-Z])?)\b`
```

You can see the result here : `https://regex101.com/r/dY7cE6/3`

But the problem is that i can't find it if it's not the first number of my string (like this address : Bâtiment **1** 32 Rue Jean Jaures 69000 Lyon)

So i ask you help to find in any situation this street's number wich is here "32".

I keep search on my own but help will be appreciate .

Thank you .

Comment: Can you explain in words the pattern you want to define?  e.g. (I'm guessing from your examples) would "always the last number in the string less than 5 digits long" do?

Comment: This is exactly this i want "always the last number in the string, except if it is 5 numbers from postal code".

Comment: This will **not** end well if you're dealing with multiple countries - especially Ireland. If you absolutely, positively have to reformat addresses you'd be better off using something like PostcodeAnywhere or Experian EDQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last number in the string, unless it's 5 digits, optionally capturing a single letter after the number:

```
^.*\b(?!\d{5}[A-Z]?\b)(\d+(?:\s*[A-Z]\b)?)
```

Comment: you're regex is ok but i need also to catch "B" if there is one in the address example :"32B" , sorry i had to be more specific on it , but i though my regex was explicit. As you can see in my regex example in my question i catch the "B" in every case .

Comment: It was pretty obvious in the regex. :-)  Edited

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will find the second to last number in the string (in the capture group).  If there is a single letter after this number (separated by a space or not) it will also capture this.

It requires the last number in the string to be a five digit postcode:

```
/(\d+(?:\s*\w\b)?)[^\d]+\d{5}[^\d]+$/
```

However, how reliably do you need to identify house number?  What is the possible range of input data?  No regex approach is likely to be very good.  [This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components) give some idea of the problems.

[See it working on the sample data](https://regex101.com/r/pE5eQ0/1).

Comment: problem is, if the number is in first position in the string that doesn't work as you can see on this example : https://regex101.com/r/dY7cE6/4 , in the first case you don't match the "32"
All possibles examples of adress datas are in my question . Number is pretty important to identify someone, and i know that this is not simple to do regex on address or not really optimal but i didn't found an othe way to do it

Comment: you're right sorry, one last problem you don't catch "B" if there is one in the address example :"32B" , sorry i had to be more specific on it , but i though my regex was explicit. Maybe you can just modify my regex which take "B" in parameter to help me .

Comment: last little question look at this case : https://regex101.com/r/dY7cE6/6 . Guess you're regex works if street's number got at least 2 numbers and not 1 ..

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(?!\d{5}\b)\d+\b(?:\s*\w\b)?(?=\D*\b\d{5}\b|\D*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/20

Comment: you're regex is really good but as i said in precedent comments, i need to catch "B" if there is one in the address example :"32B" , sorry i had to be more specific on it , but i though my regex was explicit. As you can see in my regex example in my question i catch the "B" in every case .