# regex to address if number exists

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching for php regex to split street and house number, but when address hasn't house number it should give only street name.

I have this one:

```
/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i
```

It works but when an address hasn't a house number, then it splits the last letter from the street name.

This is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT street FROM branch;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ( preg_match('/([^\d]+)\s?(.+)/i', $row['street'], $street) )
    {
       $streetName = $street[1];
       $streetNumber = $street[2];
       echo $streetName;
       echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Examples of addresses:
UL.JANA PAWLA, UL.GDANSKA 83A, UL.MOSTOWA 5

Comment: the question is unclear. Where is the input coming from and how?

Comment: please give example addresses; ones that fail and ones that succeed (or that you want to succeed). Your code block is irrelevant.

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{` that failed, *outright*. Checking for errors would have told you something about it.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Is it always `streetname number` pattern? Never the other way around?

Comment: I'm learning and I think that should be regex, this regex works but only if number exists.

Comment: the regex works eh? [I doubt that...........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282710/regex-to-address-if-number-exists#comment83549302_48282710).

Comment: If you're starting out and don't actually have production code out I suggest you redesign your data entry (forms?) and ask for the number and street name individually and store them in the DB individually. If not then play around in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Just use `\d+` and replace with nothing. It'll extract the numbers from your string and give you the string without the numbers in them

Comment: @ctwheels what about "1st Street 14"?

Comment: @Andreas correct, but that's why we don't use regex to parse addresses in the first place. See [how to parse freeform street/postal address out of text, and into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I *think* you're tring to do is:

> The Limes 45

becomes:

> Street: The Limes
>  
>   Number: 45

And your issue is that if the data is:

> Goblins Only Street

Your output is incorrect.

> Street: Globins Only
>   Number: Street

Therefore: try this Regex:

```
  \s?([^\d]+\s)\s?(\d+.*)*
```

What it does:

- If not a number collects all non-number values as a first group (street)
- If a number exists *after that point* then collects the number and all following characters as the second group.

---

Inputs:

> The Limes

Output:

```
 Street: The Limes
```

---

Inputs:

> The Limes 45

Output:

```
 Street: The Limes  
 Number: 45
```

---

Inputs:

> The Limes 45B

Output:

```
 Street: The Limes  
 Number: 45B
```

Comment: [Ahem........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282710/regex-to-address-if-number-exists#comment83549302_48282710).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner absolutely, but I was choosing to ignore the horrific code on the question.... I'm treating this as a *pure* regex question `:-D`

Comment: the OP just re-edited, I'm out. Good luck with this Martin. Side note: Just in case someone dv's, it would not have come from me ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I should be downvoting for overusing the `>` quote attribute in this answer. But the Regex works......

Comment: meh, no worries.