# Regular expression to validate street name which is allow few scenarios

Tags: javascript, regex

1. Alphabets allowed
2. Number and Special characters are not allowed
3. If you enter number one alphabet should be enter

https://www.regextester.com/

```
(^[a-zA-Z ]*)?(^[0-9 ]+[ a-zA-Z])*$
```

this expression is working only problem with when i type
123 main street it only allow 123 m i wanted to make it infinite

Comment: Add a `+` quantifier after your last class. You should not use regex to parse addresses though, it will break.

Comment: thank you ctwheels. it's working now.

Comment: Fwiw, you should do some research on address validation, your assumptions about what a correct address looks like is are pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Add `+` quantifier after your last class as the following suggests:

```
(^[a-zA-Z ]*)?(^[0-9 ]+[ a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

You should refrain from using regex to parse addresses though, it will break. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components) for more information