# How can I extract values from a string (address) in SQL using a regex pattern?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would really appreciate your help on the following problem:

I have a column containing addresses (all mixed together).
These addresses are quite heterogeneous, so a simple selection based on position won't do it. 
Thanks to helpful people on stackoverflow, I already found a regex pattern to split it up. Now the only question left is how to perform an SQL UPDATE query in order to separate the address (maybe **regexp_replace()** will do the job?).

**current format:**

```
Street 123
12343 City
```

**target format:**

```
address: street 123
zip: 12343
city: City
```

**regex pattern:**

```
^([a-zäöüß\s\d.,-]+?)\s*([\d\s]+(?:\s?[-|+/]\s?\d+)?\s*[a-z]?)?\s*(\d{4,5})\s*(.+)?$
```

So the goal is to update the columns **city** and **zip** with the relevant part of the String. The current field **address** should only contain the first line afterwards.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse freeform street/postal address out of text, and into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components)

Comment: Maybe `regexp_replace()` *would* do the job.  If so, you should change to a database that supports that functionality.  That is not MySQL.

Comment: If the current format is always exactly that, then you can split with new line and then split second row at the first space to get three columns as required.

Comment: AFAIK, Unlike MariaDB, MySql does not have regex_replace. See https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: Some things are better done in a real programming language, not SQL.