# RegEx for matching a single-line standard USPS address

Tags: php, html, regex

I am learning how to extract data from a string of data to define as variables and use as I'd like.  The data source I am parsing is a standard email every time and the address is exactly the same punctuation and format each time.  The only difference is that sometimes the zip-code may be the 9-digit code.

```
123 Riverview Pkwy, Orlando, FL 55556
123 Riverview Pkwy, Orlando, FL 55556-1234
```

I was able to extract the city like this:

```
preg_match('/, (.*?)\,/', $xaemailpaste, $insuredcity1);
$insuredcity = $insuredcity1[1];
```

And that will return "Orlando" perfectly, but I can't get the address, state or zip.  Can someone please help me with a regular expression to assign variables to each component?

```
$streetaddress = 123 Riverview Pkwy 
$city = Orlando
$state = FL
$zip = 55556
```

I have had some success with regex and I'm excited to learn more, but I have spent 2 days trying stuff and looking up things to try and I can't get the expression just right for my exact needs.

Comment: Why not just `explode()` the string by comma and then extract the zip code from the last piece. *Much* easier to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse freeform street/postal address out of text, and into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Chf0cr/2) might help you to divide your addresses into groups, where you can simply extract your listed variables:

```
([0-9]+)\s([A-Za-z0-9\-\s]+)\,\s([A-Za-z\s]+)\,\s([A-Z]{2})\s([0-9\-]{5,10})
```

[image: RegEx]

You may work on this RegEx and create additional boundaries, if you wish. It currently has five groups `()`, where groups `$2` to `$5` are your target variables.

Comment: I'd suggest `(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)` for the ZIP+4; the way you've got it there `--------` is valid.