# How to seperate a full adress string (Streetname, housenumber, zipcode, city and country) into seperate parts

Tags: python, string, split

As part of an API reponse I'm receiving an address as a string that I need to split in order to put into our own database. The address can look like the following:

```
'teststreet 1, 1234 AZ City, Country'
'teststreet 9C, 1235 AZ City, Country'
'J. teststreet 1, 1243 AZ City, Country'
```

I'm having a hard time splitting this string into its separate parts.

The fact that the street-name itself *can be two parts and that a house number might include a letter as well that should also be separated if it exists are mostly bothering me.

I've tried a few approaches to solve this by:

```
adressdetails = row['Adresgegevens'].split(",")
adress2 = [x.replace(",", "") for x in adress2]
split_house_number = re.split(r'(\d)', adress2[2])
house_number = split_house_number[1]
house_number_extension = split_house_number[2]
```

- splitting on each comma (which doesn't work for separating the postal code from the city, and because you cant split on whitespace laster because of the variable amount of whitespaces ("J. Streetname" vs "streetname" )
- Splitting on whitespaces (as partly mentioned above)
- Regex splitting on encounter of a number to seperate the house number from the extension(I don't know that much about regex so I didn't feel like I had the right approach when attempting this)

I need the response address split into the following variables:

```
streetname
house_number
house_number_extension
zip_code
city
country
```

Example:

```
"teststreet 1C, 1234 AZ New York, Australia"
```

into ->

```
teststreet
1
C
1234 AZ
New York
Australia
```

Example 2:

```
"Jh. teststreet 1B, 9870 GH Amsterdam, Canada"
```

into ->

```
Jh. teststreet
1
B
9870 GH
Amsterdam
Canada
```

Example 3:

```
"teststreet 45, 9867 HJ Rotterdam, Germany"
```

into ->

```
teststreet
45
null
9867 HJ
Rotterdam
Germany
```

Comment: *"I've tried"* doesn't show what you've tried. Please atleast show one of the many *"I've tried"* s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components

Comment: [Addresses can contain organisation names, and organisation names can contain commas.](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) For example: Society of College, National & University Libraries, 102 Euston Street, London, NW1 2HA

Comment: Says *splitting on each comma [...] doesn't work for separating the postal code from the city* and later shows three examples where splitting by comma would perfectly separate postal code from city but differ from the example pattern shown at the top of the question ... Please make sure your examples are consitent.

Comment: @shmee You're right, force of habit caused that mistake. It's adjusted. Also I've added some of the lines of code that I used but obviously didn't come very far with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NJBGVA/1)), but I don't know all your other strings, so it might need to be adjusted:

```
lst = [
    "teststreet 1C, 1234 AZ New York, Australia",
    "Jh. teststreet 1B, 9870 GH Amsterdam, Canada",
    "teststreet 45, 9867 HJ Rotterdam, Germany"
]

import re

for test_case in lst:
    m = re.findall(r'(.*)\s+(\d+)([A-Z]*)\s*,\s*(\d+\s+[A-Z]+)\s*,?\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*)\s*', test_case)
    if m:
        streetname, house_number, house_number_extension, zip_code, city, country = m[0]
        print('Streetname:', streetname)
        print('House Number:', house_number)
        print('House Number Ext.:', house_number_extension)
        print('Zip Code:', zip_code)
        print('City:', city)
        print('Country:', country)
        print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Streetname: teststreet
House Number: 1
House Number Ext.: C
Zip Code: 1234 AZ
City: New York
Country: Australia
********************************************************************************
Streetname: Jh. teststreet
House Number: 1
House Number Ext.: B
Zip Code: 9870 GH
City: Amsterdam
Country: Canada
********************************************************************************
Streetname: teststreet
House Number: 45
House Number Ext.: 
Zip Code: 9867 HJ
City: Rotterdam
Country: Germany
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I needed, thank you! Now I can spend some time learning and understanding this Regex.