# how combine multiple input texts in one variable and it belong to object in manage bean

Tags: java, jsf

I have object in manage bean , and it include address . I want display  to user interface home number input text , street name  input text...ect . but in  database just has  address column . how create  input text for each one the aggregation it in address ( when submit all values , it will data store in address column in database ) . how do this business?
I don't want change my database and use input mask.
thanks.
I using jsf ,primefaces, java 2ee
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components

Answer (score 0):

When you click on submit store home number input text , street name input text...ect in JSON format into the address filed then when you are loading parse that and take value based on the key.

**{
"homenumber": "xyz",
"name":"abc",
"street":"123"
}**

when you are loading the page you would be having the entity object and take the address column value and parse like below and assign to each managed bean field.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json =entity.getAddress();
```

JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(json);beanHomeNumber= actualObj.get("homenumber").toString();beanStreet= actualObj.get("street").toString();beanName= actualObj.get("name").toString();

Here beanHomeNumber, beanStreet, beanName are managed bean fileds.