# PHP - Handling End-User Input of Addresses

Tags: php, jquery

This is more of a general "how do *you* handle it" type of thing. I got an internal site written in PHP and jQuery that allows for admin staff to enter addresses and customer information. I've ran in to a... situation? Where they enter the address info in to a singular line instead of splitting it up (e.g. they enter "1234 Something St # 105, Sacramento, CA 95111" in a single line instead of having seperate input fields for Street Address, Suite, City, State, Zip, etc. - this was the case intially, but they *all* complained about it.). There are some instances where the Suite gets mixed in with the city on the database side. (e.g. # 105 in Sacramento shows "# 105 Sacramento" in the city field of the database instead of having "# 105" in the Street Address column).

How would you guys handle this? How would you guys program/script to keep the data clean? Idas? Suggestion? Thoughts?

I'm trying to keep the data clean so future reporting is easier and cleaner as well and to make it so we don't have to go in to do cleanup work. They're also forking over a boat load of money for this every month so it's a "they get what they want" scenario, hence not pushing back on the seperation of fields.

Positive feedback is what I'm looking for as I'm not an expert by any means, but I can do a bunch of cool things in web building.

Thanks for considering a response!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components. But really, no amount of money is worth the effort of trying to split the address yourself.